# After splitting a string, ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

Let's say that `url = "http://gmail.com"`.
I try to make from this a string `dnsname = "Top-level com"`.

Now we run the following piece of code:

```
System.out.println(url);
String[] urlsplit = new String[3];
System.out.println(url.substring(10,11));
urlsplit = url.split(url.substring(10,11));
String dnsname = "Top-level " + urlsplit[urlsplit.length - 1];
System.out.println(dnsname);
```

As output we get:

```
http://www.gmail.com
.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

I do not see the mistake I made, however there must be one.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Debug it!!  ArrayOutOfBoundsException is the second-easiest to debug (after NullPointerException).  If you don't have a good debugger just insert System.out.println calls to trace the values leading up to the error.

Comment: The output you show here is wrong. This is the output: http://gmail.com
i
Top-level l.com

Comment: Are you sure about the 10,11 or did you play with it just before you pasted the code?

Comment: @shlomi33 : He made a mistake, his actual input is `"http://www.gmail.com"` so substring(10,11) returns ".". You can see it in his outputs.

Comment: ikhebgeenaccount, do you intent to only handle URLs that only have the hostname, like `http://www.example.com`, or ones that may have more instances of `.` in them, like `http://www.example.com/query.exe?name=report&id=12#fragment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the dot is considered as the [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) pattern meaning "any character" so your split method returns an empty array. Just do the following :

```
String url = "http://gmail.com";
System.out.println(url);
//Escape the . to tell the parser it is the '.' char and not the regex symbol .
String[] urlsplit = url.split("\\.");
String dnsname = "Top-level " + urlsplit[urlsplit.length - 1];
System.out.println(dnsname);
```

If you run the same code using "." instead of "\." you will have the same problem as in your code. because s.split(".") actually returns an empty array so `urlsplit.length - 1` is negative and `urlsplit[urlsplit.length - 1]` is obviously out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to avoid the need to remember all the regex meta-characters:

```
String url = "http://gmail.com";
System.out.println(url);
String[] urlsplit = new String[3];
System.out.println(url.substring(12, 13));
urlsplit = url.split(Pattern.quote(url.substring(12, 13)));
String dnsname = "Top-level " + urlsplit[urlsplit.length - 1];
System.out.println(dnsname);
```

NOTE: you'll be better probably with:

```
urlsplit = url.split(Pattern.quote("."));
```

If you run this code you will get:

```
http://gmail.com
.
Top-level com
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) receives a regular expression, the dot (.) symbol is a special character in regular expressions, so you need to send it as a plain symbol.

Replace

```
urlsplit = url.split(url.substring(10,11));
```

with

```
urlsplit = url.split("\\"+url.substring(10,11));
```

Or simply do it this way

```
urlsplit = url.split("\\.");
```

But the question is why `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`?

Because of the wrong pattern in your `split` function the array never got populated.
And you were trying to access it second index's value so in that case it gave you an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the output

```
Top-level com
```

If this is what you're wanting given a URL, Consider using the `java.net.URL` class along with `split()`.

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        URL url = new URL("http://gmail.com/"); 
        System.out.println(url);

        String[] hostParts = url.getHost().split("\\.");

        String dnsname = "Top-level " + hostParts[hostParts.length - 1];
        System.out.println(dnsname);
    }

}
```

This outputs:

```
http://gmail.com
Top-level gmail.com
```

[java.net.URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/net/URL.html)

This also has the benefit of working with URLs that aren't only the hostname, for example, given `http://www.example.co.aq/query.exe?field=name&id=12#fragment`, this will output `Top-level aq`.